# Android - StartActivityForResult on finish() method freezes UI

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following situation:

1. Activity A starts Activity B, by using startActivityForResult
2. Activity B then returns an `ArrayList` of Strings to Activity A by using on `finish()`.

Here is a code example of what exactly Activity B does:

```
ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add("Some string");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra(KEY, urls);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Then Activity A receive the data in `onActivityResult(...)`

The issue I have is that when the user taps the done button and Activity B's code example executes, Activity B freezes for about 3 seconds (when I have about 2 strings in the `ArrayList`). The more strings I have in the `ArrayList` the longer it freezes. I have more or less determined that it is `finish()` that causes the UI thread to freeze.

Is there a way to call `finish()` without **freezing** Activity B? If not, why is this happening?

EDIT:
Here is the full example:

```
   /**
    * Background task
    */
   private class gatherUrlsTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<PictureEntry>, Integer, Intent> {

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           bt_done.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           fab_add_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }

       @SafeVarargs
       @Override
       protected final Intent doInBackground(ArrayList<PictureEntry>... params) {
           ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<>();

           for (PictureEntry pictureEntry : params[0]) {
               if (pictureEntry.isSelected()) {
                   imagePaths.add(pictureEntry.getPath());
               }
           }

           if (imagePaths.size() == 0) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.please_select_atleast_one_image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               return null;
           } else {
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.putStringArrayListExtra(SELECTED_IMAGES_KEY, imagePaths);
               return intent;
           }
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
           finish();
       }
   }
```

However I can remove everything from the AsyncTask since it did not have any effect on performance.

Comment: Could you please provide more code of activities to see what's happening?

Comment: Are y ou using an emulator or a real device? The emulator frezzes 0.5 seconds on finish() due to performance. In your case, it is also serializing the intent to return to the activity A...

Comment: No I am using a real device. Samsung S7 Edge so it has more than enough power. I am sure it is not phone specific, since it happens on my other tests devices as well.

Comment: A side note: You display a Toast in doInBackground. That is impossible as it is a GUI action. You better return  only null. And then in onPostExecute examine intent for null so you can display the Toast there. At the moment you are not even checking if intent is null in onPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks for the side note, I have changed the code. Still no fix available though!

Comment: please show us, how do you have started the asyncTask. Simply with execute()?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what is cause of that, but for prevent ui getting freezed, use asyncTask and then in the onPostExcecute call finish()